# Integral and norm

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

Consider the fonction : 
$N(x,y)=\int_{0}^{1}\mid x+ty\mid dt $ where $x,y$ are real numbers.
I have to proove that this function defines a norm $R^2$. 
First of all, I said that, by linearity :
$$N(\lambda(x,y))=\int_{0}^{1}\mid x\lambda + t\lambda y \mid =\mid \lambda\mid N(x,y)$$ 
Then, i said that because $\mid x+ ty \mid $ is positive for all $x,y$ by definition of the absolute value, then if we take the integral, it remains positive.
The problem is for the triangle inequality. I don't know if the following lines are true :

We have to proove that : $$N(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)\leq N(x_1,y_1)+N(x_2,y_2)\quad \forall (x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in R^2$$
We have : 
$$\mid x_1+x_2+t(y_1+y_2)\mid \leq \mid x_1+ty_1\mid +\mid x_2+ty_2\mid$$
Then, 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\mid x_1+x_2+t(y_1+y_2)\mid dt \leq \int_{0}^{1}\mid x_1+ty_1\mid +\mid x_2+ty_2\mid dt$$
$$
= \int_{0}^{1}\mid x_1+ty_1\mid dt + \int_{0}^{1}\mid x_2+ty_2\mid dt$$
Is that all ? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: How do you show $N(x,y)=0$ if and only if $(x,y)=(0,0)$? There should be something about the continuity of your integrand...

Comment: A norm on the real numbers is a function of the form $\varphi \, : \, \mathbb{R} \, \rightarrow \, \mathbb{R}^{+}$. How is $\varphi$ defined here ? $\varphi(x) = \sqrt{N(x,x)}$ ?

Comment: Sorry, this function is defined on $R^2$ and i have to proove that this function is a norm on $R^2$. The function is defined by : $N(x,y)=\int_{0}^{1}\mid x +ty\mid dt , \forall (x,y) \in R^2$. Maybe this is more clear know.

Comment: Given $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, you want to prove that:

$$ N\left( (x_1, y_1) + (x_2, y_2) \right) \leq N\left( (x_1, y_1) \right) + N\left( (x_2, y_2) \right). $$

The term on the left is $N\left( (x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2) \right)$ not $N\left( (x_1 + y_1, x_2 + y_2 ) \right)$ as you wrote.

Comment: Oh yes of course, I have re-edit my answer, is it true know ?